# findstr and && do not play ball together

Tags: batch-file

this is supposed to detect which error was posted from `7z.exe` to `"%temp%\error.unp"` and act accordingly. however, the `&&` after `findstr` does not work at all, the specific commands are never executed. what am I doing wrong?

```
type "%temp%\error.unp" || findstr /c:"Wrong password" && set /p "password=enter password other than fanedit.org: " && goto security
type "%temp%\error.unp" || findstr /c:"not enough space" && rmdir /s /q %drive%\$recycle.bin && echo disk was full, recycle bin emptied out.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment to Proteks answer you'll need parentheses to enclose a block.
No need to cram all in one line then.
Reacting solely on an errorlevel means you should suppress other output with `>Nul 2>&1`

**Edit: reversed redirection order due to @sst's hint**
Try:

```
type "%temp%\error.unp" | findstr /c:"Wrong password" >Nul 2>&1 &&(
    set /p "password=enter password other than fanedit.org: " 
    goto security
)
type "%temp%\error.unp" | findstr /c:"not enough space" >Nul 2>&1 &&( 
    rmdir /s /q %drive%\$recycle.bin
    echo disk was full, recycle bin emptied out.
)
```

Comment: @sst Ack changed above.

Comment: I am intrigued by that `2>&1` bit. can you explain that to someone not very familiar with the terminology?

Comment: It merges error stream 2 with standard output 1. See [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)